# Simple Recursive Methods in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am having some trouble with writing recursive methods in java.
I can do more simple ones such as the fibonacci sequence, GCD, etc.
I am required to write a recursive method to convert decimal numbers to binary and return it in String form. I am unsure though if I need to return the String result back into the method in the recursive call, or just an effective way of writing it.

```
public static String toBinary(int decimal) {...}
```

Can anyone shed some light on simple steps to accomplish this? Recursion is still a bit blurry to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are probably supposed to do is basically divide the `decimal` by two each recursion step:

- Input is even -> last bit is 0, divide input by 2 and call `toBinary` again
- Input is odd -> last bit is 1, reduce input by one, divide by 2, call `toBinary`

Then try to figure out when to stop the recursion and how to append the bits into a string.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out and see what works. Would it be wrong to have the method accept the string result as another argument to append to the string?

Comment: @ColeDooley Would not be wrong but at the same time probably not ideal, let the method return the `String` evaluation of the binary that is put in. You may start at the bottom - what happens if you put it 0, what if you put in 1, what if you put in 2 and 3, then you should start seeing how to handle the string concatenation via the recursive call.

Comment: Great, I'll try it out and see what I come up with

Comment: With integer division there's no need to reduce by one prior to dividing in the odd case.